# How to exclude Apache VirtualHost from global rewriting?

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, virtualhost, lets-encrypt

I have setup Let's Encrypt SSL certificate on my VPS, which works fine, but now all VirtualHost are trying to load over https://.

I have found RewriteRule directive in le-redirect.conf:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>


ServerSignature Off

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/redirect.error.log
LogLevel warn
```

But I am not sure how to exclude specific VirtualHost named example.com from matching https rewrite rule.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to httpd.conf or apache2.conf

```
<VirtualHost example.com>
   RewriteEngine Off
</VirtualHost>
```